# Yii2. Can't get models image path from another table

Tags: php, yii2

In Product model I have:

```
public function getImage() 
{ 
   return $this->hasMany(Image::className(), ['product_id' => 'id']); 
}    

public function getMainImage()
{
    $image = Image::findOne(['product_id' => $this->id, 'is_main' => 1]);
    return $image->path;
}
```

In view file I have ListView with _item file:

```
<img src="<?=$model->getMainImage()?>"></img>
```

Controller:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Product::find()->with(['image']),
]);
```

Error is:
Trying to get property 'path' of non-object.

Comment: Your code is not enough .. show also all the action  code

Comment: where is the `path` property i cant see any such name in the code?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have submitted may cause this error if the image was not found. 
 You should include a null check.

```
public function getMainImage()
{
    $image = Image::findOne(['product_id' => $this->id, 'is_main' => 1]);
    return $image ? $image->path : false;
}
```

You may also want to look at implementing this with an AR relation via hasOne, which would be more concise.  It is documented here:

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#hasOne()-detail

Comment: `return is_null($image) ? false : $image->path;`

little may not better, hi

Answer (score 0):

Have you write full code:

```
return is_null($image) ? false : $image->path;
```

if not working, check your condition!